# twitter api callback not redirecting?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Good evening,

I'm fairly new to PHP and I am currently having a problems with the [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) library.

I've made a connection button which redirects to the Twitter API for connection, but the problem is that after the connection it redirects me to the callback URL:

`mysite.com/callback.php?oauth_token=MyTokenOauth&oauth_verifier=MyOauthVerifier`

While this one should redirect me to another page after logging in, everything works fine on localhost ([wamp](https://www.wampserver.com/en/))

However, once on my server it stops working.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

do you update twitter's settings? callback url is valid for your server?